# Background Subtraction using a control image in Python

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, numpy, video-processing

I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4 library to preform a human action recognition application. The first step in the process is to extract the background and leave only the human figure as the foreground. I have an image of the scene, which is a controlled green screen environment. I also have various video files of people preforming actions. So far I can read the video file and background into numpy arrays and preform functions on these. My question is how do I best use these two matrices to only keep the foreground information i.e. the human figure. Thanks for reading and any help would be great.

Comment: You take its absolute difference. cv2.abdDiff()

Comment: I cant find this method in the OpenCV 2.4 documentation, could you please link it Abid?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=abs#absdiff